# How to show url in webkit View

Tags: swift, xcode, webkit

i want to show `url` in the `webkitView` like **instagram** app shows.
how to achieve this??
thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, I updated the image to be more descriptive and to understand better than I want.
↑↑↑

Comment: did you want to show url in your webkit??

Comment: Yes, but how instagram (as indicated image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I already solved my request in part, not doing it with "WebKIT", if I do not have to use "SFSafariViewController", I would only need the rounded corners

> ```
> @IBAction func abrirTalleres(_ sender: Any) {
>     let urlTallerWeb = URL(string: "https://google.com")
>     let vistaTalleres = SFSafariViewController(url: urlTallerWeb!)
>     present(vistaTalleres, animated: true, completion: nil)
>     vistaTalleres.delegate = self as? SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
> }
> ```

Image sample:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbFOT.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand by looking at the instagram app, you need to have view with a layout as you have shown in the last image with "X" button which dismisses the view and UILabel next to it which shows the URL. Below that can be your WebView. To get the rounded corner on your View only at the top, you can use below code on UI

```
CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.}].CGPath;

self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: I mean how to load the url, for example with rounded corners, when loading appears from bottom to top, to return there is an "x", etc. They have nothing to do with URL shorteners.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try 